# Use compareTo or not

Tags: java, comparator

I have to compare objects of a custom class, say A.

Comparison is simple one based on a int member, say mem, of A.

So in comparator implementation, I can either do:

```
(A a1, A a2) -> {return (Integer)a1.getMem().compareTo(a2.getMem());}
```

Or, I can do comparison on my own:

```
(A a1, A a2) -> {
     if(a1.getMem() > a2.getMem()){
         return 1;
     }else{
        if(a1.getMem() < a2.getMem()) {
            return -1;
         }else{
             return 0
          }
     }
}
```

Which one is a better approach?

First approach has far lesser lines of code, but internally compareTo does same what we are doing in second approach.

Comment: I would use neither, but `Integer.compare(a1.getMem(), a2.getMem())` to avoid the cast as well. But generally use the second approach and (almost) always try to use existing API to do your stuff and don't re-invent the wheel. This avoids bugs on your side, because you can't add issues into the comparison algorithm, like it can happen in approach 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's usually better not to re-invent the wheel. Therefore the first approach is better.

You can even write less code with [`Comparator.comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)):

```
Comparator.comparingInt(A::getMem)
```

Answer (score 4):

Go for the first approach. It is more readable (how do we compare two `A`s? `compare` their `getMem`) than a bunch of if statements and returning magic numbers. Also, using a method from the library like `compareTo` is less error prone than writing a bunch of comparison logic yourself. Imagine having mistyped a `-1` as a `1` or a `<` as a `>`.

*But*, there is an even better approach:

```
Comparator.comparingInt(A::getMem)
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the most basic rules to get to a "good" code base: avoid code **duplication** like the plague!

It is not only about writing the *minimum* amount of code to solve a problem. It is really about: not having the same logic in more than *one* place.

Why? Because when you decide to change that logic at some point, you have to remember to update all places that contain that logic.

There are studies that show that code duplication in larger project sooner or later leads to having multiple *almost* identical clones of some piece of logic. And guess what: that is where bugs are hiding. You copy 9 lines out of 10, and you make a subtle modification within that 9 lines. And either you just added a bug, or you fixed a problem in those 9 lines, but not in the original 10 lines. And now two places in your code do slightly different things. Rarely a good thing.

So follow the two other answers, but understand *why* you should do that.

And make no mistake: at some point, you might decide that this compareTo implementation is no longer what you need. Then it is perfectly fine to change it to something else, and write that down in this place in full length. But until that day: re-use that already existing code!